# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser переход по навигации

Tags: php, парсер, dom

Доброго времени суток. 
Прошу помощи, не могу понять как спарсить несколько страниц,с такой пагинацией:

```
<div class="navigation" align="center">
<span>←</span> 
<span>1</span> 
<a href="/page/2/">2</a> 
<a href="/page/3/">3</a> 
<a href="/page/4/">4</a> 
<a href="/page/5/">5</a> 
<a href="/page/6/">6</a> 
<a href="/page/7/">7</a> 
<a href="/page/8/">8</a> 
<a href="/page/9/">9</a> 
<a href="/page/10/">10</a> 
<span class="nav_ext">...</span> 
<a href="/page/229/">229</a> 
<a href="/page/2/">→</a>
</div>
```

Пытался таким макаром, но выкидывает то первую страницу , то третюю, больше ничего ...(таким способ получалось парсить по пагинации списком.) Помогите , одна надежда на вас, всю ночь ломал голову, и пол дня , никак не получается.

```
function parser_simple_html($url, $i){
    if($i < 2) {
    $html = str_get_html(get_result($url));
    $blog = $html->find("#dle-content", 0);     
if(isset($blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 0)->next_sibling()->href) && !empty ($blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 0)->next_sibling()->href)) {
            $href = $blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 0)->next_sibling()->href;
            $i++;
            parser_simple_html($href, $i);
            }
     }
 }
$i = 0;
parser_simple_html('http://дле-сайт.ру/', $i);
```

Comment: Вам необходимо с помощью рекурсии составить полный список страниц, а потом что то у же с них парсить.

Comment: спасибо большое , а не могли бы вы дать пример , или ссылку на документацию )